# How can I make refresh a Textbox from another form? C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, textbox

I'm trying to update a Textbox from another form with this code:

```cs
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Variables.revenu += Variables.LAIR * 30;
    Cartel_Form.Textbox_Revenu.Text = Variables.revenu.ToString();
}
```

But I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Cartel.Form.Textbox_Revenu'

Here is the content of the Textbox in the first form:

```cs
Textbox_Revenu.Text = Variables.revenu.ToString();
```

In the same form I can refresh/modify the Textbox but not in another form. The textbox modifier is set on public.

Comment: Is Cartel_Form instance of another form or is it a name of a class?

Comment: It is the name of the form

Comment: You can use `delegates` to update/access inaccessible part of code.

Comment: @DarshanFaldu How can I use that here?

Comment: you need to pass either the instance or an `Action<string>` to the other form. You can create a method in `Cartel_Form` like this: `public void WriteToTextBox(string text)`. inside it you place your code. Then you pass the method as parameter to the constructor of the other form

Comment: If `Variables` is a class object, you can bind the Text Property of `Textbox_Revenu` to `Variables.revenu`, so when you change that Property, the Text Property of your TextBox will be updated accordingly. No need to pass instances around. -- Use a BindingSource as *mediator*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using events where the child form contains the events while the main form listens for these events. Both forms have one TextBox and one NumericUpDown control. Or as @jimi mentioned use bindings.

**Main form**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassingDataBetweenFormsSimple
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowChildButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
            
            childForm.PassingData   += ChildFormOnPassingData;
            childForm.PassingNumber += ChildFormOnPassingNumber;

            try
            {
                childForm.ShowDialog();
            }
            finally
            {
                childForm.Dispose();
            }
            
        }

        private void ChildFormOnPassingNumber(int value)
        {
            numericUpDown1.Value = numericUpDown1.Value + value;
        }

        private void ChildFormOnPassingData(string text)
        {
            FirstNameTextBox.Text = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? 
                "(empty)" : 
                text;
        }
    }
}
```

**Child form**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassingDataBetweenFormsSimple
{
    public partial class ChildForm : Form
    {
        public delegate void OnPassingText(string text);
        public event OnPassingText PassingData;

        public delegate void OnPassingNumber(int value);
        public event OnPassingNumber PassingNumber;
        public ChildForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PassDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PassingData?.Invoke(FirstNameTextBox.Text);
            PassingNumber?.Invoke((int)numericUpDown1.Value);
        }
    }
}
```